# Docker image for dotnet core 2.1 and IIS

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile, iis-express

I Dockerized a .Net core application and my application uses IIS-express for basic authentication. 
The issue is whenever I run my app in a container I don't get data back because the basic authentication doesn't work inside the container because the Docker image doesn't have IIS-express.

Currently, I am using this image:

microsoft/dotnet:2.1.301-sdk

Is there any Docker image that contains both of .dotnet core and IIS-express?
Any other ideas!!

Comment: When you say, "using IIS express for basic authentication" -- how does IIS-express know whether to accept or reject an attempted login? Is it accepting windows login details for your machine -- if so, I don't think there is anything you can do with it that will work in docker container?

Comment: When I hit the local application page version a login popup appears but, when I use the Dockerized version it doesn't appear. IIS-express accept the credentials after it checks them in Active Directory.

Comment: I don't think a a docker container can pull that trick. Unless you are going to create your own specialised docker image that can join your AD domain. Going that route seems hard.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [microsoft/iis](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/iis/) docker image and add the dotnet core environment but it looks like it requires a Windows Container.  If you are not comfortable building custom images, then you might have to find a custom repo, or replacing IIS-express with another solution.

Comment: Microsoft/IIS image doesn't have .Net core nor power shell. It seems the best way to do it is to customize an image.

Comment: That's why I said to "add the dotnet core environment".  But if you don't feel comfortable making your own custom solution, I would suggest finding another replacement for IIS.  Sorry couldn't help you any more!

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler and quicker than you expect to not rely on iis and instead do the basic auth in code. Writing an Authorize attribute is surprising straightforward.

Here's an example: https://www.johanbostrom.se/blog/adding-basic-auth-to-your-mvc-application-in-dotnet-core. In fact, he solves it twice on one page, once with attributes and once with middleware.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to run on Windows then use this snippet from [configure Kestrel to use Windows auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-2.1#enable-windows-authentication-with-httpsys)

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args) => 
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseHttpSys(options =>
            {
                options.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Basic;
                options.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = false;
            })
            .Build();
}
```

(where the article had

```
options.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM | AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate
```

I've replaced with `options.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Basic`)

Comment: Thanks, I will try this approach.